# Autobatching in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In a situation where I have a lot of work to process but a smaller cluster, can I get Apache spark to somehow smooth out the work for me so that the cluster doesn't explode due to out of memory?

A lot of work, here, means more than the total amount of available memory.

A situation where this would be valuable would be for example when running my scheduled batch job and for some reason we have an unusual amount of data to process. This should be rare but still expected to happen. I don't want to size up my cluster just because of these rare occasions.

For these rare occasions, how can I get Apache Spark to smooth out the workload in order for it to fit the cluster and avoid out of memory? Longer execution time to handle this smoothing is acceptable here.

If the normal case would be that the amount of available RAM is far less than the amount of data that is to be processed, then of course the cluster should be grown to fit the problem.

The job will process files, each file producing one result file. Each file can be processed completely independently of the other files. Each file represents approximately the same work load and size. Pretty much a standard ETL kind of job.

To give you a feeling for the load one file represents, each file takes about 25 minutes on a dedicated 2 core computer. The load is CPU bound for most of these 25 minutes, other than the initial download and the final upload which are quite fast in comparison.

Currently I'm looping over all partitions that requires work performed. For each such partition I add all files to one list and create one RDD out of this list of files. Under normal circumstances this works just great. When I run into those rare occasions, then I run out of memory.

As the initial data in this RDD is so little data (even in the rare case), then all of it ends up in the same partition. I have a feeling this is part of my problem and I should be putting each file path in a separate partition. I have a hard time finding the documentation that support this.

Do I really have to loop over the files myself, or can Apache Spark support me in this somehow? If so, how? Does my partitioning idea sound sane?

Comment: You need to provide a sample of your code, to get us know better what is your spark flow.
But, why not pre calculate the Size of the files you gonna process and then split them into micro-batch (instead one by one).
If the files in HDFS/Another FS that support the du function, u can calculate easily the size of each file, and split them into micro-batch with well known of how much your program gonna process.

Comment: I believe this is quite a common problem typically solved by queueing and async processing of requests, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory

Comment: @ShemTov, I've updated the description now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I ran out of memory was that I got partitions that couldn't fit in RAM.

For me I had a hard time finding a good number of partitions to repartition into. I decided to count the number of rows and choose that no partition may contain more than 200 000 rows. That made my partitions small enough and more evenly sized.

Re-partitioning the data solved the problem.